# Some websites not showing in ubuntu, dual os

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-14.04

My system has Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (installed using wubi, dual os). connection through WiFi.

**Problem**: Some websites are showing **This webpage is not available** in ubuntu, but, works without any problem in my Windows 7.

(in chrome and also checked in Firefox)

What i tried, doing a ping request thru terminal.

```
$ ping github.com
PING github.com (192.30.252.129) 56(84) bytes of data.

^C
--- github.com ping statistics ---
50 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 49391ms
```

and, facebook fails also

```
PING facebook.com (173.252.120.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- facebook.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4031ms
```

Other sites, which works

```
PING superuser.com (198.252.206.140) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.140): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=307 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.140): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=293 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.140): icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=308 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.140): icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=294 ms
^C
--- superuser.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 5 received, 16% packet loss, time 5001ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =293.672/299.820/308.726/6.920 ms
```

**UPDATE**
Pinging github.com from my Windows 7, which works!

```
$ ping github.com
Pinging github.com [192.30.252.129] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.30.252.129: bytes=32 time=535ms TTL=54
Reply from 192.30.252.129: bytes=32 time=557ms TTL=54
Reply from 192.30.252.129: bytes=32 time=422ms TTL=54
Reply from 192.30.252.129: bytes=32 time=469ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 192.30.252.129:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 422ms, Maximum = 557ms, Average = 495ms
```

**UPDATE** - No firewall present it seems

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Not sure where to go from here. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You had a dropped packet on SO - if it runs for a long time, do you get significant drops?

Comment: What is SO? Can u explain it?

Comment: @sk8terboi87ツ Paul refers to [so]

Comment: Yes! But it works most of the time

Comment: I wonder why this is down voted without giving any reason or so

Comment: "*Most* of the time" can be a clue.  Please post the ping results for 50 pings like with github.

Comment: Have you defined a firewall in Ubuntu, or any other security software?

Comment: @harrymc: No. It was a fresh installation and i haven't done anything.

Comment: The firewall is installed par default. Could you verify that iptables has no rules, as [shown here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/list-and-flush-iptables-rules/). If some rules do exist, please include the list in your post.

Comment: @harrymc: There are no rules. updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried comparing MTU value in Ubuntu with that of Windows 7? From my personal experience, this more likely seems to be an MTU issue.

Try changing (reducing) the MTU value (temporarily) in steps of 10, starting from your current MTU value (most likely 1492):

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1492
```

Now, try to ping the sites and repeat the above steps. If you are able to successfully find out the MTU that works, make sure to persist the MTU for the network by editing the interface file (`/etc/network/interfaces`) and appending the below line (with the new MTU value)

```
mtu 1492
```

Comment: It worked!!! After so many attempts, it was 1465. :D (This also helped http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2110129&p=12480983#post12480983). Thx!